# Why Hooks inside UseEffect not working as I expect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

When I use useEffect with hooks inside it does not update state:

```
const App = () => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => { 
       Alert.alert('Before setLoading: ' + isLoading);
       setLoading(true);
       Alert.alert('After setLoading: ' + isLoading);
    }, []);
  ...
}
```

Both times it alerts: 
Before setLoading: false 
After setLoading: false

Can you please suggest why it behaves this way?

Answer (score 0):

when you `setState` in `useEffect`, it doesn't update immediately. it's happening because of [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877875/11171071)

### Alternative Way

you can use `useRef` instead of `useState`

```
const isLoading = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => { 
      console.log(isLoading.current) // isLoading is false
      isLoading.current = true
      console.log(isLoading.current) // isLoading is true
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is **asynchronous**, the state update **only take effect at the next render**

to see the value of `isLoading` at the next render, do this

```
const App = () => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
       Alert.alert('Before setLoading: ' + isLoading) 
       setLoading(true);
    }, []);
    
    useEffect(() => { 
       Alert.alert('After setLoading: ' + isLoading);
    }, [isLoading]);
}
```